# Update user information is not working

Tags: php, mysql, session

After pasting the data into the form and clicking on the submit button, I always get error message "wrong password," even when I paste the correct password. Can anyone help me please?

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_POST['ulozitzmeny']) && ($_SESSION['user']) && strlen($_SESSION['user']) > 0) {

    $first_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['jmeno']);
    $last_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['prijmeni']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $password = hash('sha512', mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['heslo']));

    $res = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM users WHERE username='$_SESSION[user]'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

    if ($password != $row) {

        echo" <div id='alerts' class='alert alert-danger'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>Chyba!</strong> NespĂˇvnĂ© heslo!
             </div>";
    } else {

        if (mysql_query("UPDATE users SET first_name='$first_name', last_name='$last_name', email='$email' WHERE username = '$_SESSION[user]'")or die(mysql_query)) {

            echo" <div id='alerts' class='alert alert-success'>
             <a href='#' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-label='close'>&times;</a>
             <strong>ĂšspÄ›ch!</strong> ZmÄ›ny probÄ›hly ĂşspÄ›ĹˇnÄ›!               
             </div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can't tell till we see what your HTML form looks like, nor the db schema, nor do we know what's inside `dbconnect.php` and if you're using the same API as the rest of your functions. check for errors, you're not doing that. Nor do we know if there's a value for `$_SESSION[user]`

Comment: HTML form: http://pastebin.com/MkUHDSuJ and I checked everything about dbconnect.php here is everything ok.

Comment: password is a string and row is an array......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
if ($password != $row) {
```

to

```
if ($password != $row[0]) {
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Manual says:
mysql_fetch_array — Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both.
And in if statment you compare maybe $password which is string and $row which PHP manual says is array.
Pls check value of $row variable.